# Let an object loop as array with a foreach() by extending ArrayObject

Tags: php, foreach, arrayobject

So I have an object which contains a set of objects in a private data member. I can now loop it with a `for` loop by overriding the `count()` function of an `ArrayObject` and `offsetGet($index)`, but I also want to loop it within a `foreach` loop.

What functions do I need to minimally extend to add this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the SPL Iterator Interface see http://uk.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php for details

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK You can use directly `foreach` on `ArrayObject`:

```
$ao = new ArrayObject(array(1, 2, 3, 4));
$res = 0;
foreach($ao as $el) {
    $res += $el;
}
echo 'ArrayObject elements sum: '.$res;
```

**SAMPLE:** http://codepad.org/uQDGQ03A

Comment: An object can be used with a foreach loop when it a) is an array or b) implements the Traversable interface. ArrayObject implements this interface (see http://php.net/manual/class.traversable.php).